# perl how to force boolean to 0/1

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a 0 or 1 in a value for true/false. Here's the code:

```
use strict;
my %h = (Y => "y");
my $bool_x = 1 & exists $h{X};
my $bool_y = 1 & exists $h{Y};
print("x $bool_x y $bool_y\n");
```

I needed to add the "1 &" to force it to not be the empty string. Is there a better way to do this? I realize that it's an artifact of the way perl prints the false value, but I need it to be a 0 not the empty string.

Comment: the false value is both 0 *and* the empty string.  you presumably need it to be `'0'` :)

Comment: yes. I need to convert it to a real zero.

Comment: This feels a bit like an XY problem. Why do you need numerics here?

Comment: I'm storing the value into a database. So I need to get a real 0 / 1 out of the results from exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is just:

```
$bool || 0
```

Comment: I really doubt that any realistic solution is so inefficient that it matters to anybody. Programmer efficiency, and hence readability, is paramount here

Comment: @Borodin then it becomes a matter of taste. I'd go with `$bool ? '1' : '0'` as the most straightforward way to turn a bool into a 0 or 1 string.  But many are ternaryophobes.

Comment: I don't like the ternary in this case because I don't want to add an if. Silly, maybe, but I like the straight forward math operations for this.

Comment: This is sufficient for the OP as mob in reply called it "numification", however if somebody searches in this question or from google here rather the opposite, the boolean from a number, for something similar to type/boolean conversion as in php, as me needed, the mob's second part of answer `0 + !!$var` , or this mine suggestion `($val!=0)*1` work

Answer (score 3):

Your code is far from clear. The `&` operator is a *bitwise* operator that behaves differently on numbers and strings, but `exists` returns a value that will obligingly be the number zero or the empty string depending on what is required of it. [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators) has this to say

> Although no warning is currently raised, the result is not well defined when this operation is performed on operands that aren't either numbers (see Integer Arithmetic) nor bitstrings (see Bitwise String Operators)

So because the result of `exists` is one such value your code is on shakey ground

There is no need to write something arcane, and if you want to represent Perl's internal *true* and *false* values by a different pair of values then the conditional operator is the correct choice

```
my $bool_x = exists $h{X} ? 1 : 0
```

I believe that's the most readable without being verbose, and that's all that matters here. It's also applicable to any other pair of values that you may choose, such as

```
my $bool_x = exists $h{X} ? 'Y' : 'N'
```

Comment: so the value returned by exists being boolean isn't suited for arithmetic operations? I was avoiding the ternary because I didn't want to add an if. silly perhaps, but just my outlook on things.

Comment: @kdubs: That is a very odd choice, especially when you're dealing with non-numeric boolean data whose behaviour is as good as undefined in Perl and impossible in most languages

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to "numify" a true/false value.

If `$var` can contain 1 or any false value, all of these will evaluate to either "0" or "1":

```
0 + $var
0 | $var
$var || 0
1 * $var
1 & $var     (you discovered this one, already)
chr(48+$var)
sprintf "%d", $var
```

These constructions return a 0/1 value when `$var` can contain any true or false value:

```
0 + !!$var      ( !! true => 1, !! false => "" )
1 - !$var
$var ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: the !!$var didn't appear to work on it's own. so why bother if you are just going to add the 0 + anyways?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I just messed up, that's why it doesn't make sense.  I was playing with !!exists($h{X}), but your example uses !!$var.  The !!$var converts it to the an inverted boolean value, and then to the original boolean variable. So you need the !! to do the conversion. Exists is already boolean, so the !! didn't do anything to it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mob: While there are clearly endless ways to do this, the OP is asking *"Is there a better way to do this?"* and I think a gallery of villainy doesn't answer the question. Wouldn't a bottom-line recommendation be appropriate?

Comment: @kdubs: I think you're misunderstanding how Perl handles boolean tests. There are values that Perl considers to be *true* or *false*, and special internal values that Perl uses when it wants to return a true or false value. There are no *boolean values* as such. A construct such as `$a && $b` will evaluate to one of `$a` or `$b` depending on their values, and not to any magical boolean type. I think it might be useful if you explained why you want to do this, as the only reason I can think of is that you need these values to be represented in a particular way externally

Comment: what I really need is a zero or one to write into a file. So I need a way to convert the value returned by exists into that.

Comment: @kdubs: Well you shouldn't really be relying on the *true* value being `1` either so I would still go for a conditional expression. You can have `print exists $h{X} ? 1 : 0` or `if ( exists $h{X} ) { print 1 } else { print 0 }` but I can't see a nicer way that doesn't presume things that I don't think you should. Imagine if `exists` returned the strings `'T'` or `'F'`, I don't think you'd be thinking along the same lines. You seem to be concerned about efficiency at an assembler level which isn't approprizte

Comment: yeah. I do think like that at times. just my background.

Comment: You might want to "boolify" prior if you want to convert it to boolean, express that it is set, and numify after not to hide the boolean value, eg `$val = $val!=0` after `$val=$val*1` or together $val = ($val!=0)*1, but thanks for your contribs, your second part also does the same things eg yours $var=`0 + !!$var`